# Accessing second Json javascript object sub array

Tags: javascript, python, json, object, request

Assuming this return jscipt request.jon object

```py
[
    {
        "code": 20,
        "country": "US",
        "intldes": "1959-007A",
        "launchDate": "1959-09-18",
        "launchNum": "7",
        "launchPart": "A",
        "launchYear": "1959",
        "name": "VANGUARD 3",
        "orbitalApogee": "3255",
        "orbitalInclination": "33.34",
        "orbitalPerigee": "510",
        "orbitalPeriod": "124.52",
        "result": {
            "ECI": {
                "posX": 0.4294413044,
                "posY": 1.1939786497,
                "posZ": -0.8195909042,
                "velX": -0.0506349163,
                "velY": 0.0216010068,
                "velZ": 0.0046956546,
            },
            "geography": {
                "alt": 3262.6082167209,
                "lat": -32.9755706775,
                "lon": 92.9968105081,
            },
            "satelliteInfo": {
                "classification": "U",
                "idLaunchNumber": "007",
                "idLaunchPiece": "A  ",
                "idLaunchYear": "59",
                "orbit": 33670,
                "rightAscension": 156.1412,
                "satnumber": 20,
            },
        },
        "size": "MEDIUM",
        "tle1": "1    20U 59007A   22354.80744419  .00001354  00000-0  56471-3 0  9995",
        "tle2": "2    20  33.3385 156.1412 1661563  89.7607 289.2392 11.56436417336706",
        "type": "PAYLOAD",
        "updated": "1671726243",
    }
]

S = requests.get(url)
if s.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
print('invalid response - %d: %s' % (r.status_code, r.text))
sys.exit(1)
return s.json()
```

Trying to access the value of the second nested array "geography" for the value of "lat" but getting key error when i try to do a simple:

`print ( str(s['result']['ECI']['geography']['lat']))`

this notation works no issue If i use the first sub-array `["ECI"]["posY"]` as an example

`print ( str(s['result']['ECI']['posY']))`

Is there a notation I am missing because geography is a second nested object in the return?

Comment: Wrong tag,need to add [tag:python]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
s['result']['ECI']['geography']['lat']
```

try:

```
s['result']['geography']['lat']
```